# Using a switch/case with group tableView populated through an array

Tags: ios, switch-statement, uitableview

I am populating a tableView through an array which has sections in it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

group01List = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Row 1",@"Row 2", nil];
NSDictionary *group01Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:group01List forKey:@"Group"];
group02List = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Row 3",@"Row 4", nil];
NSDictionary *group02Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:group02List forKey:@"Group"];

[listOfItems addObject:group01Dict];
[listOfItems addObject:group02Dict];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

That works fine and I am getting right in the View the way I want them.

Now I have a URL linked to them, which they show in the display and if I have one section, I can just use the Switch/case way to link the cells to the different URLS, like so:

```
        switch (indexPath.section){

case 0:switch (indexPath.row) {       
    case 0:
        fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLDismissKeyboard_h_Comments];
        break;
    case 1:
        fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLDismissKeyboard_m_Comments];
        break;
}
case 1:switch (indexPath.row) {  
    case 0:
        fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLDismissKeyboard_h];
        break;
    case 1:
        fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLDismissKeyboard_m];
        break;
}
```

The strings have been #defined at the top - so all good.

But when I want to use groups in my TableView, I am lost how to change this.

I have this code which would link my didSelectRowAtIndexPath to the right section, but since I am using a NSURL (fileURL) in the switch, **I need to somehow combine them**.

```
     NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
     NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Group"];
     NSString *selectedGroup = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Any help would be heaps appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be totally understanding the question, but if you are using sections along with rows, your switch should look something more like this:

```
switch (indexPath.section(
{
case 0:
    switch (indexPath.row) 
    {
    case 0: 
         fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLDismissKeyboard_h];
         break;
    case 1:
         fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLDismissKeyboard_m];
         break;
    }
    break;
case 1:
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that was the case as it looked promising, but the result doesn't change as it sees the second group as a copy of the first group. The Labels are correct, as in it sees the groups, but dont the links. - Have updated the code with your answer to see if any other things can be thought off. Cheers

Comment: I fear I've misunderstood your intent somehow. Let's try and get that straightened out. So, for Group 1, Rows 1 & 2, you want to return kStringURLDismissKeyboard_h/_m, right? Now, for Group 2, rows 1 & 2, what do you want to return? (Keep in mind, the row is zero-based within the section, so your "Row 3" would be section 1, row 0.)

Comment: Yeah so Group 1 (which is section 0) needs to have row 1 and row 2 which link to kStringURLDismissKeyboard_h/_m respectively and then there is Group 2 (which is section 1) that has row 3 and row 4 that need to link to kStringURLDismissKeyboard_h_Comments/_m_Comments respectively - sorry I swapped them around when I updated my code. Hope this makes sense :-)

Comment: Your answer got me thinking when you embedded a switch statement within a switch and said that the first row was 0- Instead of switch (indexPath.section) it needed to be if (indexPath.section == 0)